# How do I stop the home button from waking the device?

Tags: cyanogenmod, standby

I keep pressing the home button by accident in my pocket.

I have an S5, Cyanogen Marshmallow, rooted and xposed.

I can't find any way to stop wake on home with cm.  For Touchwiz there are xposed modules which stop this... How do I stop it on CM?

Comment: I can't confirm this for CM13, because I no longer have access any CM13 device, but on CM14 and on LineageOS there is a _Home Button_ section in the settings for hardware buttons. It does have a _Wake Device_ option that can be toggled on or off.

Comment: [pocket lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paep3nguin.pocketLock) which works on proximity / gravity sensor is well rated and may do the trick for you

Comment: @Duane Dibley thanks, I found it. I'm used to Touchwiz and it's a pleasant surprise when I don't have to struggle to customise my device! I also salute your good taste in telly :)

Answer (score 0):

The setting was in *Settings › Buttons* – just toggle off *Wake Device* there. Duh!